# Mat-input for each value of the array

Tags: html, angular

What i am trying to do here is display input boxes for each of the people using ngFor. However this only lets me make selection from the first input box and when i make the selection it automatically updates the remaining inputs with the same value. Can anyone help me understand what i could be doing wrong here and i would like to be able to update the values for each person from the people array individually

```
 <table>
        <tr>
            <td class="detailS">Hours</td>
            <td style="width: auto" nowrap class="opt">
                <mat-list>
                    <mat-list-item class="item"
                        *ngFor="let member of people.value; let i = index">                               
                        <div style="margin-left: 50px" nowrap>Start</div>
                        <div style="margin-left: 30px" *ngIf="edit">
                            <mat-form-field>
                                <input matInput [matAutocomplete]="startAuto"
                                    formControlName="start" (click)="onChooseStart()"
                                    required="true">
                                <mat-autocomplete #startAuto="matAutocomplete"
                                    (optionSelected)="onStartSelected($event)">
                                    <mat-option *ngFor="let time of filteredStart | async"
                                        [value]="time">
                                        {{time | amDateFormat:'h:mm a'}}
                                    </mat-option>
                                </mat-autocomplete>
                            </mat-form-field>
                        </div>
                        <div style="margin-left: 50px" *ngIf="!edit">
                            {{start?.value}}
                        </div>
                        <div style="margin-left: 50px" nowrap>End</div>
                        <div style="margin-left: 30px" *ngIf="edit">
                            <mat-form-field>
                                <input style="width: 70px" #endInput matInput
                                    [matAutocomplete]="endAuto" (click)="onChooseEnd()"
                                    formControlName="end" required="true">
                                <mat-autocomplete #endAuto="matAutocomplete"
                                    (optionSelected)="onEndSelected($event)">
                                    <mat-option *ngFor="let time of filteredEnd | async"
                                        [value]="time">
                                        {{time | amDateFormat:'h:mm a'}}{{getDifference(formGroup.get('start').value, time)}}
                                    </mat-option>
                                </mat-autocomplete>
                            </mat-form-field>
                        </div>
                        <div style="margin-left: 50px" *ngIf="!edit">
                            {{end?.value}}
                        </div>
                    </mat-list-item>
                </mat-list>
             </tr>
         </table>
```

Comment: Could you create an [mcve] that better illustrates your problem? I recommend using https://stackblitz.com, that should be easier to read than a dump of a component's template code.

Comment: You should be able to do it in [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) if you're clever in minimizing your code :).

Comment: I think the major problem however is that you likely only have one `FormControl` with the name `start` defined, so when it sets the value of `start`, all of them get the same value, as they are all bound to the same control...

Comment: @HereticMonkey: Thanks for the solution . Do i need to dynamically update the formControlName and set and get for each of them ? . Is there a easier way around this ?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, `FormArray`s are the solution, but I must admit I've not run into the situation myself, so I'm not to up-to-date on how to fix it (which is why I commented and didn't answer :)). I'd look at [the Angular documentation for Dynamic Forms](https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-form#dynamic-forms) as it appears to be what you're looking for.